# Pretty-Printing of F# DU does not work

Tags: f#

I am struggling with pretty-printing (%A) [this DU](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/95fb299ab8588b112246f986148de9da8dbc9a4b/src/absil/il.fs#L992).

The local `instr` is of the type `ILInstr`.

I would have expected `sprintf "%A" instr` to result in `I_stloc 0us`, but as you can see in the locals window (please see `instr_str_A`), it just shows the typename.
All three different format strings(%A, %O, .ToString()) result in the same output.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I then tried it in interactive with [a simpler DU](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/), but that works:

```
> type Contact = Email of string | Phone of int
let email = Email "bob@example.com"
printfn "%A" email    // nice
printfn "%O" email    // ugly!
;;
Email "bob@example.com"
FSI_0002+Contact+Email
```

A few things which may or may not be relevant:

- The DU is private
- This is inside VisualFSharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler
- Following, it uses the proto-compiler, not the regular compiler. Is the proto-compiler maybe not feature-complete?

Comment: I think you should be printing `st` not `instr`?

Comment: What is your question? Also: post code, not screen shots.

Comment: Do you mean when debugging the compiler? If so, how do you print the output? Note that the locals/watches windows pretty much show the underlying C# representation of things and ignore the nice F# features...

Comment: I think the idea is that `instr_str_S` should be `I_stloc 0`

Comment: Sorry, when I posted the question it was late and I was a bit grumpy. (Should have just gone to bed and asked later...) I have clarified a bit what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Best way to get help - post some actual copyable code with output and why that output is wrong